# Setting a subdomain under my DOMAIN.eth

Tags: ens

I have my primary DOMAIN through the Ethereum Name Service.  I see documentation that shows you can set subdomains as I would like to do this for security for an up-coming ICO.

So I would like to register ICO.DOMAIN.eth to point to the contract for the ICO that way the address can't get changed on my site like has happened in the past.  Plus it seems easier for ICO participants to enter the ICO.DOMAIN.eth.

Is there a way to do this?  On the ENS site I see a mysterious section "CONTENT HASH FOR APPS (IPFS/SWARM)", is this where I register the ICO subdomain and if so how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the answer.  I don't know why it was so difficult as there is a tool that has been developed on the same "ENS.DOMAINS" site, but under MIST there is no link that I could find from the "Registrar.ens.domains" to this tool.  Enter this URL into your MIST browser and it lets you create Subdomains:
http://manager.ens.domains/

Now I can create the ICO.ETARDIS.ETH subdomain as well as other subdomains to prevent hackers from changing the Ethereum address on my site like has happened in the past.  This seems like the safest way to prevent a hack of this type.